# Spring boot cannot find postgresql function (data type mismatch)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, function, spring-boot

Developed a function. I've moved all the sql codes I've written on the Java side here.
In the function I have created, the first and second parameters are waiting for big integer type data. I am trying to send the long-defined data on the spring boot side to big integer and send it to this function. In the mean time, it gives me the error of **"org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException"**. I mentioned the error contents below.

> ERROR 21952 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function fn_subscriber_to_iservice(numeric, numeric, character varying, character varying, double precision, double precision, double precision, numeric, numeric, bytea) does not exist
>     İpucu: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>     Position: 15

**The function is as follows.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."fn_subscriber_to_iservice"("_service_id" int8, "user_id" int8, "_start_date" varchar, "_end_date" varchar, "total_price" float8, "total_month" float8, "price_per_person" float8, "_start_station_id" int8, "_end_station_id" int8, "passengerlist" "public"."_passengers_array")
```

**The Spring boot codes**

```
StoredProcedureQuery subscriber = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("fn_subscriber_to_iservice");
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(6, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(7, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(8, BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(9, BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    subscriber.registerStoredProcedureParameter(10, List[].class, ParameterMode.IN);

    subscriber.setParameter(1, BigInteger.valueOf(payload.getService_id()));
    subscriber.setParameter(2, BigInteger.valueOf(userDetail.getId()));
```

I expect your help on this. Thanks

Comment: try SET NOCOUNT ON on stored procedure.

Comment: not to show the number of rows affected? I have to return a result to the "spring boot" side. @Alien

Comment: @Alien I used the parameters in integer type. In queries, I have converted to big integer type. The problem has disappeared.

Comment: coool...happy coding